# Python package with sample datasets but deferred download?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, dataset

I have a data analysis tool that I made a Python package for and I'd like to include some sample datasets, but I don't want to include all the datasets directly in the Python package because it will bloat the size and slow down install for people who don't use them.

The behavior I want is when a sample dataset is referenced it automatically gets downloaded from a URL and saved to the package locally, but then the next time it is used it will read the local version instead of re-downloading it. And this caching should persist permanently for my package, not only the during of the Python instance.

How can I do this?

Comment: For inspiration, you might want to check how _nltk_ does it: http://www.nltk.org/data.html -- but there are for sure plenty other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a folder under AppData using the `appdirs` package

---

`datasets.py`

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandasgui.utility import get_logger
from appdirs import user_data_dir
from tqdm import tqdm

logger = get_logger(__name__)

__all__ = ["all_datasets",

           "country_indicators",
           "us_shooting_incidents",
           "diamonds",
           "pokemon",
           "anscombe",
           "attention",
           "car_crashes",
           "dots",
           "exercise",
           "flights",
           "fmri",
           "gammas",
           "geyser",
           "iris",
           "mpg",
           "penguins",
           "planets",
           "tips",
           "titanic",
           "gapminder",
           "stockdata"]

dataset_names = [x for x in __all__ if x != "all_datasets"]

all_datasets = {}

root_data_dir = os.path.join(user_data_dir(), "pandasgui", "dataset_files")

# Open local data CSVs if they exists
if all([os.path.exists(os.path.join(root_data_dir, f"{name}.csv")) for name in dataset_names]):
    for name in dataset_names:
        data_path = os.path.join(root_data_dir, f"{name}.csv")

        if os.path.isfile(data_path):
            all_datasets[name] = pd.read_csv(data_path)

# Download data if it doesn't exist locally
else:
    os.makedirs(root_data_dir, exist_ok=True)

    logger.info(f"Downloading PandasGui sample datasets into {root_data_dir}...")
    pbar = tqdm(dataset_names, bar_format='{percentage:3.0f}% {bar} | {desc}')
    for name in pbar:
        pbar.set_description(f"{name}.csv")

        data_path = os.path.join(root_data_dir, f"{name}.csv")

        if os.path.isfile(data_path):
            all_datasets[name] = pd.read_csv(data_path)
        else:
            all_datasets[name] = pd.read_csv(
                os.path.join("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamerose/datasets/master/",
                             f"{name}.csv"))

            all_datasets[name].to_csv(data_path, index=False)

# Add the datasets to globals so they can be imported like `from pandasgui.datasets import iris`
for name in all_datasets.keys():
    globals()[name] = all_datasets[name]
```

Comment: Am I understanding it right that you are saving the files where the packages are installed (in subdirectories of `site-packages`)? I would strongly advise against it. It's a best practice to save in one of the user's directories instead, see for example `user_data_dir` of [_appdirs_](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/).

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks for the advice! I changed to your suggestion... I also did something weird by adding items to `globals()` since I want to read datasets programatically but also be able to import them individually like `from pandasgui.datasets import iris`. I'd appreciate your opinion if this is also bad practice, I couldn't think of a better way

Comment: The first sentence of the answer isn't true anymore, is it? -- Personally I am not a fan of dynamically adding things to any namespace (globals, module, class, etc.) in order to avoid possible clashes with user's code and also make it easier for linting tools, etc. I'd rather add things to a well-known list or dict. But I do not know enough about this one particular use case to have a strong opinion.

Comment: @sinoroc Ah yes, edited it again. And yeah I see a lot of people saying adding things to `globals` is bad but since this is a module that users import from, then using `globals` inside it should never actually pollute the user's scope any more than defining variables explicitly inside this module would. I'll come back and edit if I do find any issue with this use-case. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: I think it might become an issue for linting tools (_pylint_, etc.). They won't be able to find `pandasgui.datasets.utils`, since it doesn't exist until the code is actually executed. And on the other hand some tools, might execute the code and thus trigger the download unknowingly to the user, so make sure to safe guard the code (in a function for example or with a `if __name__ == `__main__` condition).

Comment: @sinoroc Another good point about the linting, thanks. I changed it so the names are hard coded into `__all__` which fixes the linting (at least for PyCharm). Regarding triggering the downloading automatically upon import, this is my desired behavior. I'm aware import side effects are frowned upon but want to keep required user interaction to a minimum, so going to keep that for this project. And I think downloading datafiles to AppData is unlikely to silently break anyone's code, which is the main reason I think side effects are evil